# R "for loop" error messages {}

Tags: r, for-loop, error-handling

Since a couple of days ago when I run a for loop in R it gives me plenty of errors related to "}". It only happens if I highlight the whole code and run it. If i execute it line by line, then it runs just fine.

I tried even with the most basic loop:

```
foo <- seq(1, 100, by=2)
foo.squared <- NULL
for (i in 1:50 ) {
foo.squared[i] <- foo[i]^2
}
```

Here is the console:

```
> foo <- seq(1, 100, by=2)
"rror: unexpected input in "foo <- seq(1, 100, by=2)
> foo.squared <- NULL
"rror: unexpected input in "foo.squared <- NULL
> for (i in 1:50 ){
"rror: unexpected input in "for (i in 1:50 ){
> foo.squared[i] <- foo[i]^2
"rror: unexpected input in " foo.squared[i] <- foo[i]^2
> }
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"
>
```

Details of the R session (I run it in RStudio):

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit)
```

It has been very annoying!! I would appreciate any advice!!!
Thanks,
Maria

UPDATE:

Here is the code in the very beginning that I suspect causes this problem..It is supposed to take a vector of names and extract the second element from it.

```
splitnames <- strsplit(as.character(train$Name),"[,.]")
firstelement <- function(x){x[2]}
sapply(splitnames,firstelement)
```

After I execute it R acts weird. Though I am not 100% sure.

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. Start with a new session and make sure you haven't submitted anything else (end all functions, close all parentheses and brackets, etc) before you run it.

Comment: hey. Thanks for the comment. I completely restarted the R session. But the errors still happening. Not sure if i need to just reinstall the R/RStudio...

Comment: no, don't do that. Can you post the rest of your code here? just edit your original post

Comment: Why are you running such and ancient `R` version? The mere fact that your error messages lack the initial "E" suggests something's really wacked in your setup.

Comment: i did it.. and still it did not help. I added an update to my question. I think that function may be part of the issue..

Comment: i updated my R (R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)) and still same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have been experiencing the same problem, and have found that it is caused by a bug in RStudio (the code runs fine in R and R-gui, but fails in RStudio.) It is hard to reproduce until something gets corrupted in RStudio's saved state, after which the behaviour is pretty consistent.

Removing `~/.rstudio-desktop` fixed the issue for me.

```
mv ~/.rstudio-desktop ~/rstudio-desktop.old
```

More on resetting RStudio's state on various platforms [here.](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200534577-Resetting-RStudio-s-State)

Comment: oh thanks Paul, for a moment I thought I was just going crazy!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the issue was in using the R script that I downloaded from a website. I ended up reinstalling R and saving my own R script as a new file. I am not sure what and how, but now it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I am also using Rstudio and get the same error message when running for loops.

```
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"
```

If I source the file, like this...

```
source('~/.active-rstudio-document')
```

or if I simply click the "source" button in the GUI, I don't get the same error message.

If sourcing the whole R script is not an option, consider copying the for loop to another file and sourcing that.